# Own template in "Surround with" action

Tags: php, phpstorm

Is there any possibility to **create own teamplates** which will be used with "*Surround with*" (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) or "*Surround with live template*" (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)?

For example, I would like to create template for HTML which will be surrounding selected text with PHP comments:

```
<?php /* SELECTED TEXT */ ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy -- it's ordinary [Live Template](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm) -- just with special `$SELECTION$` variable used.

For example:

```
try {
    $SELECTION$
} catch ($TYPE$ $$$VARIABLENAME$) {
    Logger::log($$$VARIABLENAME$);
    $END$
}
```

---

**P.S.**
I suggest to create and *use own groups* for your own templates and not create them in existing/bundled groups: easier management (backup/sharing/etc); no possible screw ups when bundled ones will be updated in next major version etc.

Comment: The `$SELECTION$` was all I need. Thanks! And thank you for extra suggestions :).